# ChangePassword control and setting regular expression for new password

Tags: asp.net, validation, change-password

This seems like it should have a simple solution but I can't seem to find it.

I'm using the `ChangePassword` control in an ASP.NET 2.0 application, using both the `ChangePasswordTemplate` and `SuccessTemplate` to define custom styling. The textboxes have IDs as follows

Current Password Textbox ID = **CurrentPassword**
             New Password Textbox ID = **NewPassword**
Confirm New Password Textbox ID = **ConfirmPassword**

For `DRY` reasons, I want to use the regular expression that is defined in the Custom Membership Provider to validate the new password client side. Unfortunately, setting the `ChangedPassword` control's property as follows

```
ChangePassword.NewPasswordRegularExpression = 
    Membership.PasswordStrengthRegularExpression;
ChangePassword.NewPasswordRegularExpressionErrorMessage = 
    "Regex Error Message";
```

in `Page_Init` sets the expression to the expected value, but does not cause client side validation to happen on the new password (the page posts back and the standard Membership `ChangePassword` failure text gets displayed).

I could use a `RegularExpressionValidator` in the `ChangePasswordTemplate` and set the `ValidationExpression` property to `Membership.PasswordStrengthRegularExpression` but the best way that I can see to do this requires recursing through the controls in the template to find the `RegularExpressionValidator` and setting the property, which makes me believe that there must be a more elegant way. I have other validator controls in the template (required fields and a compare validator), in case this may be causing a conflict with using the `ChangePassword` validation properties.

My question is then, does the `ChangePassword` control's `NewPasswordRegularExpression` property work when using templates or do I need to go down the `RegularExpressionValidator` control route?

**EDIT:**

Offered up a bounty on this as I can't find a definitive answer as to why the `ChangePassword` control's `NewPasswordRegularExpression` property does not validate client side.

Comment: what are your membership provider settings?

Comment: The Membership Provider settings are irrelevant in this case. I know that everything works as far as the Membership Provider goes. The question concerns the `NewPasswordRegularExpression` property of the `ChangePassword` control. The regular expression used in the Membership provider is `^.*(?=.{10,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$`

Comment: I do not mean you to answer question. Just check/play little with provider settings. it should work. also check with NewPasswordRegularExpressionErrorMessage

Comment: I don't believe that the provider settings are a problem here. The `MembershipProvider` property of the `ChangePassword` control is set to my Membership Provider and I know this to be working as the default failure message includes details set in the provider (min password length, no of non Alphanumeric characters, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use "Convert to Template", the RegularExpressionValidator control is not created automatically and therefore not rendered to the final page.  This can be confirmed by viewing the page source before and after converting to template.

To add a RegularExpressionValidator exactly like the one ASP.NET uses without the template, define it between the NewPassword TextBox and the RequiredFieldValidator like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="NewPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="NewPasswordRegExp" runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" Display="Dynamic"
    ControlToValidate="NewPassword" ValidationGroup="ChangePassword1"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NewPasswordRequired" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="NewPassword" ErrorMessage="New Password is required." 
    ToolTip="New Password is required." ValidationGroup="ChangePassword1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

You can't use the ChangePassword's NewPasswordRegularExpression property to change the regular expression at this point.  You'll have to do this instead:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegularExpressionValidator validator
        = ((RegularExpressionValidator)(ChangePassword1.Controls[0].FindControl("NewPasswordRegExp")));

    validator.ValidationExpression = Membership.PasswordStrengthRegularExpression;
    validator.ErrorMessage = "Regex Error Message";
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Andy- I'd already implemented it with near identical code to this, but I thought that there must be an easier way. Looks like there isn't :)

Comment: You're welcome.  If we pried deeper we could probably figure out exactly why Convert to Template doesn't output the RegularExpressionValidator, but I doubt it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it took me too long to come back.

PasswordStrengthRegularExpression is validated at server side. and NewPasswordRegularExpression validated at client side. And here is the difference. Due to bug in JSScript/VSScript Regx validation, every regular expression which is validated at server will not validated in browswer.

Additionally the password is get validated with NewPasswordRegularExpression as well PasswordStrengthRegularExpression. So NewPasswordRegularExpression should not break the rule defined in PasswordStrengthRegularExpression.

e.g.

```
passwordStrengthRegularExpression="^*(?=.{7,})(?=(.*\W){1,})(?=(.*\d){1,})"
NewPasswordRegularExpression="^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\W).*$"
```

works fine.

Hope this helps you.

**Update**: regex lookahead bug. 
http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-lookahead-bug

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I don't think this is the issue in this case. If the regularexpression is hardcoded to the control then it does work on IE. As far as I can see the format of the regex is in accordance with that laid out in the linked article. Since the regex being used for validation in the `ChangePassword` control template is the same as that being used in the Membership Provider, their validation is mutually inclusive (if one correctly validates they will both validate). My understanding was also that the `NewPasswordRegularExpression` would validate both client and server side